# If radio button answer is echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, radio-button

I want to check if the value of the radio is some value and if it is, it needs to echo a text line.

I use this code for the radio buttons:

```
<li>
    <label for="recommend_field"><?php echo $this->__('Would you recommend this product to a friend?') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
            <?php foreach ( $this->getOptions() as $option ): ?>
            <label>
            <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio-group" value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>"<?php if ($option['value'] == $value) echo ' checked="checked"' ?>><?php echo __($option['label']) ?></input>
            </label>
            <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
</li>
```

And I currently echo the entire value of the radio button with this line:

```
<?php echo $this->__('Would you recommend this product to a friend?') ?> <?php echo $this->getAnswer() ?>
```

The values of the radio buttons are 
1. Yes 
2. No

I want to check if value is Yes and if so echo 'Value is Yes'.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: you want to echo 'Value is Yes' after radio button is selected ?

Comment: When do you want to this check to be run? When a value is selected from the radio buttons or when the form is submitted? This will also determine whether or not you need PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <li>
<label for="recommend_field"><?php echo $this->__('Would you recommend this product to a friend?') ?><span id='ans'></span></label>
<div class="input-box">
        <?php foreach ( $this->getOptions() as $option ): ?>
        <label>
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio-group" value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>"<?php if ($option['value'] == $value) echo ' checked="checked"' ?>><?php echo __($option['label']) ?></input>
        </label>
        <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
</li>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('input:radio[name=radio-group]:checked').change(function () {
        if (this.value == 'Yes') {
        $('#ans').html("Value is Yes");
        }
        else if (this.value == 'No') {
            $('#ans').html("Value is No");
        }



}); 


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, you are using PHP to get your HTML code ready for the browser. So, your code snippet should only be responsible for generating the HTML code for the radio button group. Your PHP code will not run in the browser, but in the server. That is, if you want to know what user has selected in the client side (browser), you will need to use Javascript/jQuery to interrogate DOM to get the selected value from the radio button group, as shown below:

```
// jQuery implmentation
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_button').click(function() {
    var selected_value = $("input[name=radio_group]:checked").val();
  });
});
```

If you want to echo the value in the PHP, you need to wrap your radio button group and a submit button within a FORM and make a POST request back to the server where you can use PHP to echo the value.

Hope this helps.